# Kubernetes: How to use Gt operator in pod nodeAffinity

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I was going through Kubernetes documentation for node affinity and match expression under it. Among other operators it listed Gt and Lt (which I think is abbreviation for Greater than and less than respectively). I was thinking about how can I use them or what could be valid use cases for them but could not think of any.

Can you tell what are the possible use cases for Gt and Lt to be used in node affinity and how will I use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**values** in **matchExpressions** is an array of string. If you use Gt or Lt as the **operator**, the **values** array must have a single element, which will be interpreted as an integer.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: with-node-affinity
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/e2e-az-numeric-value
            operator: Gt
            values:
            - 100
  containers:
  - name: with-node-affinity
    image: k8s.gcr.io/pause:2.0
```

The pod will run on a node if the node's label has a key **kubernetes.io/e2e-az-numeric-value** with value that is greater than **100**.

Comment: Can you please direct me to some reference guide or documentation

Comment: Actually I didn't find any documentation that says about Gt or Lt operator directly. But after some googling I found the following line on prometheus-operator's git repo and that was convincing to me. These two operator must work like this.

https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/be7ac03166b8fca8db4e23ea69f62b8e65006391/bundle.yaml#L1941

Comment: in my case I had to put the number (`100` in this example) into quotes, so `"100"` to work.